# CTRL key is being pressed automatically

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ctrl

When I log into my Windows 7, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is being pressed automatically, even from the bootmenu. So, I am unable to choose the different options in the boot menu - as well as not being able to press the password characters. I need to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key forcibly with sometime.

After that it dramatically entering the password. In Ubuntu it is working fine. 
How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not hardware?

Comment: It might be..Suggestion?

Comment: Change your keyboard!

Comment: Not that.Even I am using USB keyboard which works fine for others.It also does the same problem here.

Comment: Are you using Virtual Machine or Dual Boot? If Windows7 installed through the virtual machine - the problem might be in virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

It seems happens to a lots of people. But why there is no permanent solution. This is definitely not sticky key issue. It happens on my both laptops. Must be some firmware issue. Temporary solution is open up the "on screen keyboard" and close it, then it will back to normal for "a while"..

Comment: The on screen keyboard is not accessible from the boot menu...